# Delete question but retain answerer's bounty?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I just [recently asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284333/issue-with-apostrophe-in-odata-request-with-javascript) about a tricky issue I was running into.

First, I had gone through SO and found Q and A's on the same topic - I tried applying them but they weren't quite working for me. Thinking my situation was unique I posted a question myself with a lengthier and more detailed explanation. I did not receive any responses so I put a bounty on it.

I received a couple answers after the bounty, neither worked but one of the responders stuck to it trying to fix it.

While trying his solution I discovered that, either I was cached or there was an unrelated problem - because the original Q/A's on the site I implemented actually did solve the issue. I awarded the bounty to the answerer, since even though his solution wasn't the fix, he did spend a bit of time on it and led me to discover everything was working.

My question in the end is just a duplicate. I feel it should be removed, but I also don't want to strip the bounty away. What would be the best course of action to take here?

Comment: Deletion rules and retention of rep with bounties recently changed:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele

Comment: Thanks @rene I read I couldn't delete a question myself after a bounty is awarded, so my thought was to reach out to a moderator. Can a moderator delete my question then, but the bounty will still be retained?

Comment: I didn't read into the exact rules nor do I know what policy mods now follow for these bounty cases. You have to wait for one of them to respond then

Comment: The number of Truly Hard Problems is quite low.  The number of ways programmers turn a simply problem into a hard problem is innumerable.  So what happened is entirely normal, and somebody else is bound to get caught the exact same way.  Deleting the Q+A would be a big waste of time and effort and is not going to help anybody that falls into the same trap.  You can safely assume that a mod is not going to do this.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - maybe I am thinking too much into it. The question is somewhat rare, so leaving it open probably isn't that big of a deal. Considering that, I've thought about posting the conclusion myself and using that as the answer pointing back to the original source.

Comment: Asking to get your question closed as a duplicate of the best of the answers that did help when you bypassed caching might be a good idea.  You could specify which questions are appropriate in a comment to help people.  You could also explain why the bonus is awarded, etc.  One option would be a self-answer which would explain the reason, closing the question and allowing you to explain what you've explained here (a cross-reference to this might not go amiss).

Comment: As the one that received the bounty, I'm not bothered if I lose it. Like many people here, I'm just happy to help someone out

Comment: "Closed as duplicate without being deleted" is a viable state and sounds like the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'd suggest not deleting the question and adding a self-answer explaining the actual root cause and the final solution (if known), which you can later mark as accepted (to not leave the question hanging as unanswered). Maybe giving due credit to the answerer who's activity eventually lead to the root cause identification.

It could still be a useful Q&A:

- to someone else falling into the same trap
- someone can simply learn about the trap's existance and avoid it in the future
- someone could learn about ways to approach/investigate a problem similar to yours

As a positive side effect the bounty and the effort put into the question and the answers don't get lost :)

If the root cause remains unknown but the issue is somehow resolved the question could be closed with the "no longer reproducible" reason. It won't get automatically deleted because it has upvoted answer(s), so the above advantages remain applicable.

Comment: I like this approach, it's a rare chance - but if someone is debugging it the same way maybe it could help further point them in the right direction as it did for me. I'll go this route. Thanks!